# Identify this set - dark blue plates, trans-blue canopy, trans-yellow & trans-red bits

Tags: set-identification

[image: whats included]526R6 - Lego bag with large 5 then box under with 526R6 under it...

Unsure what this bag makes, also need instructions.

526R6 - Lego bag with large 5 then box under with 526R6.

There are also 2 smaller bags inside but 1 has yellow, red, and grey pieces.

Also bag says 2015 The Lego group and also in another spot has what I believe to just be a generic bag number 135149.

Any help is extremely greatly appreciated!!!

I have included a picture this time as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

The minifigure seen in the photograph, which looks like a "black iron man", is quite unique - it's [sh258 "Warmachine"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sh258) and it appears only in one set: [76051-1 "Super Hero Airport Battle"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76051-1).

[image: Set 76051]

Note also the trans-darkblue canopy, and the trans-black tower windows.